# How to configure Kafka MQTT connector to subscribe to all MQTT topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect

I’m using a [Kafka MQTT connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-mqtt/current/mqtt-source-connector/overview.html) to duplicate topics from my MQTT broker into my Kafka cluster. This works great so far but I can't make the connector to subscribe to all topics.

I have tried different configurations but none of them work:

- With `mqtt.topics="#"` or `mqtt.topics="topic/#"`, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid usage of multi-level wildcard in topic string: "topic/#"
```

- if I remove the quote: `mqtt.topics=#`, I have this error:

```
ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=mqttConnector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:184)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Is it possible to subscribe to multiple topic using a wildcard # ?

The complete properties file if needed:

```
#
# Copyright [2018 - 2020] Confluent Inc.
#

name=mqttConnector
tasks.max=1
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector
mqtt.server.uri=ssl://localhost:8883
mqtt.topics=#
mqtt.username=my-username
mqtt.password=my-password

confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
confluent.topic.replication.factor=1

# Auto topic Creation
topic.creation.enable=true
topic.creation.default.replication.factor=-1
topic.creation.default.partitions=-1

# SSL
mqtt.ssl.trust.store.path=myStore
mqtt.ssl.trust.store.password=my-password
mqtt.ssl.key.store.path=myStore
mqtt.ssl.key.store.password=my-password
mqtt.ssl.key.password=
```

Comment: Is `mqtt.topics` a required property?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes it is